# Open api 3.0 java code generator - How to generate instantiated lists?

Tags: java, swagger, code-generation, openapi, openapi-generator

A few weeks ago, we migrate our project Swagger 2.0 files to Open api 3.0. We use the Java code generator to generate our classes.

With the Swagger 2.0 and the swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar, the lists where generated like that:

```
private List<Betriebspunkt> ist = new ArrayList<Betriebspunkt>();
private List<Betriebspunkt> plan = new ArrayList<Betriebspunkt>();
```

Now, with Open api 3.0 and openapi-generator-cli-3.3.2-20181022.194157-15.jar, my object is generated like that:

```
private List<Betriebspunkt> ist = null;
private List<Betriebspunkt> plan = null;
```

My yaml file looks like that:

```
Zuglauf:
  properties:
    ist:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Betriebspunkt'
    plan:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Betriebspunkt'
  type: object
```

I don't want my lists declared as null. I looked in the generator java options (https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md), but I didn't find any solution. Is there any way to get my lists instantiated?

Comment: Paste your OpenAPI 3.0 spec into https://editor.swagger.io and make sure there are no syntax errors. Also, can you try Swagger Codegen CLI v3 ([snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.4-SNAPSHOT/)) and see if makes a difference?

Comment: @Helen: Thanks for your input. I checked my spec with the online editor and there are no syntax errors. I tried to generate my code with Swagger Codegen CLI v3 and the result is the same.

Comment: Consider opening issues in the [Swagger Codegen issue tracker](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues) and the other codegen project.

Answer (score 3):

I've filed https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/1683 for [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to have lists declared properly instead of defaulting to null, e.g. https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/1683/files#diff-8afdfb3025e9e2e0e52f9f5748a2f969R54. Please have a look to see if that's what you're looking for.

PR merged into master and will be included in the 4.0.0-beta release on Dec 20th.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great, I will give it a try! The next release is planned for this week, right?

Comment: Yes, the PR (merged) will be included in the release 4.0.0-beta on Dec 20th.

Comment: 4.0.0-beta has been released: https://twitter.com/oas_generator/status/1079727020374806529. Please check it out when you've time.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has stopped working in version 4.1.1 and 4.1.2.

Comment: Please try v4.1.3. If it's still an issue, please open an issue for tracking: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new